# Aws LambdaLogger vs native ILogger

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, aws-lambda

I have been using the native `ILogger` to log Lambdas in Cloudwatch without any problems since forever.

Recently I saw AWS has a package called `Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore`. I looked at the docs and it seems it is just another logger library.

Is there any real advantage of using the AWS logger instead of the native one?

Comment: No, internally Amazon.Lambda.Logging.AspNetCore uses ILogger implementaton itself. So no such major advantages.